# Drop All Database Objects fail in liquibase

Tags: ant, liquibase

when i am trying to **drop all objects from a database using Liquibase**, its getting error. After running in debug mode i found that its trying to drop sequence after dropping table. So get a error ' sequence not exists'.
I am running in a schema named "1", But in public schema it build successfully(not trying to drop sequences).

Here is my ANT target:

```
<target name="dropAll" depends="prepare" >
    <dropAllDatabaseObjects 
            driver="${db.driver}"
            url="${db.url}"
            username="${db.username}"
            password="${db.password}"
            defaultSchemaName="${db.schema}"
            promptOnNonLocalDatabase="yes"
            classpathref="classpath"
            />      
</target>
```

Here is the log error:

```
[dropAllDatabaseObjects] Executing EXECUTE database command: DROP TABLE "1"."database_change_log" CASCADE
[dropAllDatabaseObjects] Executing EXECUTE database command: DROP TABLE "1"."database_change_log_lock" CASCADE
[dropAllDatabaseObjects] Executing EXECUTE database command: DROP TABLE "1"."party" CASCADE
[dropAllDatabaseObjects] Executing EXECUTE database command: DROP SEQUENCE "1"."party_id_seq" CASCADE
[dropAllDatabaseObjects] Release Database Lock
[dropAllDatabaseObjects] Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE "1".databasechangeloglock SET LOCKED = FALSE, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID =1
[dropAllDatabaseObjects] Successfully released change log lock

BUILD FAILED
D:\Liquibase 3.3.2-ems\common-model\build.xml:90: Unable to drop all objects from database.
    at   liquibase.integration.ant.DropAllTask.executeWithLiquibaseClassloader(DropAllTask.java:31)
    at liquibase.integration.ant.BaseLiquibaseTask.execute(BaseLiquibaseTask.java:82)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
    Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: sequence "party_id_seq" does not exist
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:316)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:112)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.dropDatabaseObjects(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:753)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.dropAll(Liquibase.java:743)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.dropAll(Liquibase.java:730)
    at liquibase.integration.ant.DropAllTask.executeWithLiquibaseClassloader(DropAllTask.java:28)
    ... 17 more
   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: sequence "party_id_seq"does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:405)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:397)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:314)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Thanks for creating https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2256 to track the bug

Comment: I also get an error on dropAllObjects. The error message says 'dropAllDatabaseObjects doesn't support the "username" attribute'.

'username' is the db user name as set in the DataSource configuration. 

Liquibase version 4.17.2